# Is there a way in app router nextjs to solve the "not implemented navigation ( except hash changes )"

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am testing an small app using App router, the current version of Nextjs Framework.

But I was dealing with mock to solve this error "Error: Not implemented: navigation (except hash changes)"

So I am using this mock in setup.js file:

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
  value: {
    ...window.location,
    href: 'http://localhost/doctors',
    assign: jest.fn(),
    replace: jest.fn(),
    reload: jest.fn(),
    toString: jest.fn(),
    pathname: '/doctors',
  },
  writable: true,
});
```

But the error persist, is there any alternative? I want to test when someone click an anchor tag ( next Link) and see if the current pathname is EX: /doctors.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.